# SLES11 - DBD: Can't load driver file apr_dbd_mysql.so

Tags: drivers, apache-http-server, mysql

We're trying to set up a htaccess authentication with user data from a MySQL database.
The part of vhost.conf looks like that:

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "host=<XXX> dbname=<XXX> user=<XXX> password=<XXX>"

DBDMin  4
DBDKeep 8
DBDMax  20
DBDExptime 300
```

Now we are experiencing issues when trying to get apache running:  "DBD: Can't load driver file apr_dbd_mysql.so" referencing to the line where *DBDriver mysql* is called.
Zypper/Yast says that the following is installed (or not):

```
S | Name                 | Summary                               | Type      
--+----------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------
i | libapr-util1         | Apache Portable Runtime (APR) Library | package   
  | libapr-util1         | Apache Portable Runtime (APR) Library | srcpackage
i | libapr-util1-devel   | Apache Portable Runtime (APR) Library | package   
i | libapr1              | Apache Portable Runtime (APR) Library | package   
  | libapr1              | Apache Portable Runtime (APR) Library | srcpackage
i | libapr1-devel        | Apache Portable Runtime (APR) Library | package
```

So all the libapr stuff seems to be there, but we just don't get the right module.

Apache (2.2.21) has been compiled as following:

```
 Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_authn_file.c
  mod_authn_dbd.c
  mod_authn_default.c
  mod_authz_host.c
  mod_authz_groupfile.c
  mod_authz_user.c
  mod_authnz_ldap.c
  mod_authz_default.c
  mod_auth_basic.c
  mod_cache.c
  mod_dbd.c
  mod_filter.c
  util_ldap.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_env.c
  mod_expires.c
  mod_headers.c
  mod_setenvif.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_ssl.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_mime.c
  mod_asis.c
  mod_vhost_alias.c
  mod_negotiation.c
  mod_dir.c
  mod_actions.c
  mod_alias.c
  mod_rewrite.c
  mod_so.c
```

And MySQL (5.5.32) is installed as well...

Do you guys have any steps for me to do, for getting the connection between apache and mysql? Really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There's also the libaprutil1-dbd-mysql package.

Pretty sure that's what you're missing!